# Ansible AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'XX is undefined

Tags: templates, ansible, conditional-statements

Can anyone please help me here, I have a playbook which has the following vars:

```yml
  vars_files:
    - "../vars/location.yml"
```

The `location.yml` has the following declared:

```yml
  loc: "{{ inventory_hostname[0:3] }}"
  location_file: "/root/ansible/vars/{{ loc }}.yml"
```

So from hostname `location_file:` is then `prd.yml`, this file contains the line:

```yml
txm_QA_access: false
```

Now if I run the playbook which copies a sudoers template with the following conditional specified in it:

```
{% if txm_QA_access %}
%Sudo-admin ALL= /bin/su - admin
%Team-QA ALL= /bin/su - admin
%Team-QA\ OffShore\ \(UK\) ALL= /bin/su - admin
{% endif %}  `
```

When I run the playbook I get an error:

```sh
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: `txm_QA_access` is undefined"
```

Where am I going wrong? Isn't it defined as a Boolean which is `false` so in theory it should skip adding those lines in the sudoers template?

Any help appreciated spent hours on this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention doing anything to include the variables in `prd.yml`, so I'm going to assume you haven't. You'll need to use [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html) to load the variables from that file.

If you are doing that, I recommend adding debug tasks immediately before your template task to sort out exactly which variable is causing the problem.

Comment: Even if I add `vars_files:
 - location_file: "/root/ansible/vars/{{ loc }}.yml"`
It still throws same error. prd.yml just has
`---
txm_QA_access: false
`
I can't see why it doesn't pick up the boolean

Comment: Hey Thanks, you were correct, I did an echo of the variables and saw prd.yml but I mistakenly thought it was being called in fact it was not -  Thanks for taking time to help

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is because the vars file `prd.yml` (most likely) is not getting loaded. And as @dechandler10 mentioned, you can use `include_vars:`, instead of `vars_files:`.

In your playbook you have already included `location.yml`, next you should include vars from `prd.yml` *before* the `template` task.

```yml
  vars_files:
    - '../vars/location.yml'

  tasks:
    # Your 'location_file' variable set to: /root/ansible/vars/prd.yml
    - name: include variables
      include_vars:
        file: '{{ location_file }}'
```

Now that your `prd.yml` has been included, the variable `txm_QA_access` will be available for template.

**However, Ansible already has built-in mechanism called `group_vars` and `host_vars`.**

Instead of having to define variable paths with `inventory_hostname[0:3]`, Ansible can directly load variables for hosts or groups with this method. See [organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables).